# json tree in python

Tags: python, json

When I load a json tree in python

> > > tree = json.loads('["SBARQ", ["WHADJP", ["ADV", "How"], ["ADJ", "far"]], ["SBARQ", ["SQ",["VERB", "is"], ["NP", ["NOUN", "Yaroslavl"], ["PP", ["ADP", "from"], ["NP+NOUN", "Moscow"]]]], [".", "?"]]]')

It seems stores tree as something that looks like a nested list

```
>>> print tree
[u'SBARQ', [u'WHADJP', [u'ADV', u'How'], [u'ADJ', u'far']], [u'SBARQ', [u'SQ', [u'VERB', u'is'], [u'NP', [u'NOUN', u'Yaroslavl'], [u'PP', [u'ADP', u'from'], [u'NP+NOUN', u'Moscow']]]], [u'.', u'?']]]
```

What does the u mean? How is this tree stored? How should I traverse/search the tree? I'm new to json trees and there doesnt seem to be many good tutorials for beginners for json trees. Can someone can explain the basics of what is going on or link me to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u'foo'` thing is a Unicode string: a string whose elements are Unicode characters instead of bytes. Don't worry about it.

The return value of `json.loads()` is a normal Python object, in your case a list.
Some of the elements in that list are also lists. You use the list the same way you
use all Python lists. See [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and 
[more tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).